# need angularjs ng resource and ui router sample to handle spring data rest relationships

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, spring-data-rest, angularjs-ng-resource

There are plenty of examples of using ng resource and ui router for basic crud operation, but I don't find any project code samples for handling rest calls related to relationships (one to may, etc).

Can any one give me references for handling one to many , many to many, etc relationships using ng resource and ui router to handle spring data rest calls on server side.

Comment: angular doesn't know or care what server language or framework you are using. There are numerous ways to approach relationships depending on use case. Question is too broad

Comment: I second @charlietfl. DB relation has nothing to do with Angular. You can use $respurce for rest API call to make basic CURD operations but that has to be written on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `SpringDataRestAdapter` for angular (http://guylabs.ch/project/angular-spring-data-rest/) has the features you need?

It auto-generated angular resources based on `_links` in received objects.